# Using chance.js to place a random word into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im sure this is probably a stupid question...

Im using chance.js because I want the main `<h1>` on my site to display something different each time you reload the page.

So if i put the following into my functions.js file:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    document.write(chance.pick(['hello', 'GDay']));
});
```

how to I get the word to appear inside my `<h1> </h1>` tags in my html file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<h1>` tags an ID, like this:

`<h1 id="title">text here</h1>`

Then, instead of `document.write`, do something like this:

`$("#title").html(chance.pick(['hello', 'GDay']));`

Comment: Thanks thats great.... One more thing i'm curious about, but not sure of. What if i wanted to use the same method, but to drop a random directory name into a file path? EG:

image/random-directory/blue.jpg

Comment: I suppose you could build up the string in JavaScript and then change the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag  you're trying to change.

Answer (score 2):

The document.write method will output that text where it is called. If you call it between the  tags, it will output that text between the  tags.

Comment: Very old-school, but totally correct and probably the simplest solution.

Comment: Right. My preferred solution would be to use jQuery, but I wasn't sure if the OP was using jQuery.